# Problems using existing sqlite database in app

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am a beginner android developer.
I am developing an app which uses a database with a bit complex database schema.

So what i did was to first create a database add tables, triggers and  Views.
I also added sample data.

I read some online tutorials on how to use an existing db in android app and got the code.

I have the db in assets folder as required and the code to copy the db to the application folder.

The problem is that the  code might be copying an empty db. With emulators , i first have to manually drag and drop the db file from the assets folder to the application folder for it to work.

Whereas the actual db file size is 5000kb, the code only copies a file of 3000kb.

When I connect  an actual android device  to my laptop and run the app, it fails because what the code copies is an empty database with out tables, views..etc.

I have also created an actual apk file and installed it  on the emulator using adb tool. It has also failed.

I have also noticed that with an actual android phone, i can not physically drag and drop the db to app folder i think due to permissions restrictions.

Even if it worked, it is not feasible.

So I am wondering whether the problem is with the code? Below is what I am using.

```
// database helper variables
private final  Context mycontext;
private  static String DB_PATH="data/data/com.example.metermanager/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME;
public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

public SQLiteDatabase getDb(){
    return myDataBase;
}

public DatabaseHelperClass(Context context,String databaseName){    
    super(context,databaseName,null,1);
    this.mycontext=context;
    try{
        Log.v("Path",DB_PATH);
        DB_NAME=databaseName;   
        Log.v("name",DB_NAME);
        openDataBase();         
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("gezaaako",e.toString());
    }
}

public void createdatabase() throws IOException{
    boolean dbexist=checkdatabase ();
    if(!dbexist)    {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        copydatabase();
    } else {
        Log.d("Exits","Db Exist");
    }
}

private boolean checkdatabase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb=null;    
    try{
        String myPath=DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
        checkDb=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        Log.e("InCheckDatabasesub",e.toString());
    }
    if(checkDb!=null){
        checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb!=null;
}

private void copydatabase(){
    InputStream myinput = null;
    try {
        myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String outfilename=DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
    FileOutputStream myoutput = null;
    try {
        myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] buffer= new byte[1024];
    int length;
    try {
        while ((length=myinput.read(buffer))>0){
            myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase()  throws SQLException
{
    String myPath=DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
    Log.e("CheckPath",myPath);
    if (myDataBase==null){
        try {
            createdatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        myDataBase=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    return myDataBase;
}
public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDataBase!=null){
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Ronald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [this Library](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to do the coping from the assert-folder and it handles the access right restrictions very good. It also takes a `zipped` database which saves a lot of space of your app size.

Comment: Thanks you so much!. Going to try it.